# Update list items in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

My data structure in AWS DynamoDB looks like this:

```
{ key: 'roomNameOne', 
  value: {
    attendees: ['A', 'B', 'C'] // this is a set,
    wsConnections: [{ connectiondId: 'foo', domain: 'xyz.com' }, { connectiondId: 'bar', domain: 'xyz.com' }]
  }
}
```

```
{ key: 'roomNameTwo', 
  value: {
    attendees: ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    wsConnections: [{ connectiondId: 'foo', domain: 'xyz.com' }, { connectiondId: 'bar', domain: 'xyz.com' }]
  }
}
```

Now when I get a request that connectionId: foo is lost, I want to remove that entry from all the items.

So after DynamoDB update operation my list should look like this:

```
{ key: 'roomNameOne', 
  value: {
    attendees: ['A', 'B', 'C'] // this is a set,
    wsConnections: [{ connectiondId: 'bar', domain: 'xyz.com' }]
  }
}
```

```
{ key: 'roomNameTwo', 
  value: {
    attendees: ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
    wsConnections: [{ connectiondId: 'bar', domain: 'xyz.com' }]
  }
}
```

Can you please help me with the query for update? The trick here is I don't know the room names, but while connection, I am aware of what all room names a connection is interested in.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, DynamoDB does not allow for this type of operation on a complex attribute (e.g. list of maps).

Modeling one-to-many relationships using complex attributes is a useful pattern.  However, one of the drawbacks of this approach is that you won't be able to perform the types of operations you're describing.

If you have access patterns that require you to update `wsConnections`, you might consider modeling the relationship by making each entry of the `wsConnections` list it's own item in DynamoDB. For example

[image]

Storing your data in this way would make it easier for you to remove connections.  For example, if you wanted to remove `bar` from your connections, you could perform the following operation

```
ddbClient.delete({
    TableName: "YOUR_TABLE_NAME",
    Key: {PK: "roomNameOne", SK: "wsConnection#bar"}
  })
```

EDIT: If you don't have access to the PK, your only option is a `scan` operation.

```
ddbClient.scan({
    "TableName": "YOUR TABLE NAME",
    "FilterExpression": "contains(#key, :value)",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
      ":value": {
        "S": "foo"
      }
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
      "#key": "connections"
    }
  })
```

This will `scan` the entire database looking for items whose `connections` attribute contains "foo".  This will let you fetch the list of items, which you can then update and persist back to DDB.

This approach is not ideal.  The `scan` operation will search the entire database, which can be horribly inefficient.  You'd also have to issue multiple requests to DDB; one to fetch and one to update.  multiple roundtrips aren't the end of the world, but again, not ideal.

To unlock more flexible and efficient access patterns, it would be ideal to get the data out of the `wsConnections` list attribute.  As long a the data is buried in a complex attribute, your options will be limited.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but when a wsConnection is lost, I don't get to know about the PK.

Comment: I see.  i've added my thoughts to the answer.

Comment: A new global secondary Index pointing to connection atributte (using the Seth modeling suggestion) would be a solution, right? Because would evict the scan.

Comment: @Henrique Fernando yes, a secondary index would work as well.   However,  you can't define a secondary index on a value within a complex attribute.